# How to double the memory for the second try for a snake rule

Tags: snakemake

I tried to figure how to automatically double the memory for a given rule. I put memory and CPU allocation in the configure file:

```
Test: "--mem=20G --cpus-per-task=10"
```

This is my test rule:

```
rule Test:
    input:
        "A.txt"
    output:
        "B.txt"
    params:
        rulename = "test",
        batch = config["test"],
     shell: """
         ......
     """
```

This is my snakemake command:

```
snakemake \
    --cores 100 \
    --retries 2 \
    --cluster 'sbatch {params.batch}'
```

I wonder if there is a way in the rule or profile to automatically double the memory in the second try after the first one fails, something like the following in profile:

```
set-resources:
    Test:
        mem_mb: attempt * resources.mem_gb
```

Or something like the following in the rule:

```
def get_mem_mb(wildcards, attempt):
    return attempt * resources.mem_gb

        
rule Test:
    input:
        "A.txt"
    output:
        "B.txt"
    params:
        rulename = "test",
        batch = config["test"],
    resources:
        mem_mb=get_mem_mb
     shell: """
         ......
     """
```

I have read the snakemake document and online forums, but have not found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#dynamic-resources) has several examples of using lambda or input functions for increasing memory with successive attempts, but they have a fixed starting point.  I think you are asking about a mechanism to do this more automatically, which doesn't seem to be implemented.  You may be able to change your sbatch command like in [this issue](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1231).

I'd use a custom function, something like:

```
def increment_memory(base_memory):
    def mem(wildcards, attempt):
        return base_memory * (2 ** (attempt - 1))
    return mem

rule Test:
    input:
        "A.txt"
    output:
        "B.txt"
    params:
        rulename = "test",
        batch = config["test"],
    resources:
        mem_mb=increment_memory(20_000)
    ...
```

This cuts down on boilerplate if you need the logic in multiple rules and is easy to add/remove.  You have to supply the base memory as an integer, you would need additional logic to parse and handle a string like `20G`. I've opted to double the memory at each retry, e.g. retry 3 will use 4x the memory. Also note the [retries directive](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#defining-retries-for-fallible-rules) if you don't want to retry every rule.

Hope it helps!